# Auto rig pro Shape keys tutorial

Tags: shape-keys

Is there any good tutorial for basic shape keys related to Auto Rig pro for recommendation?
I watched a video and tries to make my own but somehow i have 2 problems,

1. It doesn't create a range shape change from 0 to 1 in the animation.It just keep at the same number when the animation plays.
2. So instead i tried a non auto rig pro rig. In the end, i found another problem, i can't change the numbers in the shape keys windows to set any from 0 to 1.
   I tried watching another video, mention to set the keys, that i need to click the DIAMOND SHAPE to set the keys but somehow on my blender there is only this arrow symbol and i can't click it. Thank you

[image: arrow symbol]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it. By deleting the driver, it solves my 1st and 2nd problem. It was the only thing that stops me from keying the shape keys.

Comment: If there's a driver attached to a field (shown in purple), you won't be able to manually adjust it because the driver controls its value!